How do I renew TLS/SSL certificate on AWX 21.0.0.0
I need help renewing my TLS/SSL certificate on AWX 21.0.0. I'm not sure what the process is for renewing a previously configured SSL certificate. I did not install/configure this instance.
$ kubectl get pods -n awx
NAME                                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE
awx-registry                                       1/1     Running   5 (326d ago)    722d
awx-postgres-0                                     1/1     Running   5 (326d ago)    722d
awx-registry-pr                                    1/1     Running   4 (326d ago)    616d
awx-55ccbf9f66-vdqfz                               4/4     Running   20 (326d ago)   722d
awx-operator-controller-manager-675865446d-cs7vf   2/2     Running   15 (326d ago)   723d

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!
